# How to display a new page in specified postion using bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image] look at this image, i need exactly like this

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2 well">
                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-header"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Ged</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">System</li>
                    <li><a href="#">System staus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Gsetup</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> ASetting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Drives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Power Setting</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="firmware.html" id="firm">Firmware Update</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
                  </ul>
             </div>
            <div id="content_inner_nosidebar">
           </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

All this list item will come left side , and when i click this list related page should display on right side. Am using bootstarp class. And i like to use fluid grid system. But how can i load a new page right hand side of this list while clicking this list.?

I created a div "content_inner_nosidebar" inside this main div . when ever i click any of the left side list it should display all data in "content_inner_nosidebar".

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#firm").click(function(){
        $("#content_inner_nosidebar").append("/path/firmware.html")
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use jquery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#firm").click(function(){
        $("#content_inner_nosidebar").load("/path/firmware.html")
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is the best answer :)